# Numbers made up of primes from a given set

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, multiplicative-number-theory

Take a set $\mathcal P$ of primes and denote by $\langle \mathcal P\rangle $ the set of all natural numbers composed of primes from $\mathcal P$.  If
\[ \sum _{p\in \mathcal P}\frac {1}{p}\]
converges then it can be shown without too much trouble that
\[ \sum _{n\leq x\atop {n\in \langle \mathcal P\rangle }}1\ll x/\log x.\]
Is is possible to get an asymptotic result for this count?  I suspect that if we know something about the sizes of the elements of $\mathcal P$ then we can say something with sieve methods, but in this generality is it still possible to say something?

Comment: I'd ask your question up front and then give context

Comment: It seems likely that Theorem 4 in Pollack's paper
http://pollack.uga.edu/HRmult5.pdf (A generalization of the Hardy--Ramanujan inequality and applications) could be applied (or an earlier result of Shirokov, cited there). If the set of primes has counting behaving like x/(log x)^{\beta} for a \beta > 1, there's something in Wirsing's 1961 paper:

E. Wirsing, "Das asymptotische Verhalten von Summen über multiplikative Funktionen" Math. Ann. , 143 (1961) pp. 75–102

Comment: mathworker21 - ye, i've actually now taken out the context, not really necessary for the question (i think i just wanted to write out the argument cleanly for my own sake).

so-called friend - cool!  will have a look, thanks

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: (I should have read the question more carefully: I don't want to claim that these references settle the question in full generality. But they should give an asymptotic formula for "most" naturally occurring examples of \P.)

Comment: don't worry, i read your answer as "it will help you to look at these references", which it did:)

Comment: Two references which are possibly useful: 1) Erdős, P.; Ruzsa, I. Z.
On the small sieve. I. Sifting by primes.
J. Number Theory 12 (1980), no. 3, 385–394.        2) Hildebrand, A. (1-IL)
Extremal problems in sieve theory.
Analytic number theory (Japanese) (Kyoto, 1994).
Sūrikaisekikenkyūsho Kōkyūroku No. 958 (1996), 1–9. See mathscinet:https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1467991

Comment: @ChristianElsholtz thanks for those references!